# Varibles are overwriten in C+YACC, why?

Tags: c, arrays, yacc, overwrite

I have the next yacc file:

```
%error-verbose
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define DEFAULT 0
#define SHOW    1
#define ASSIGN  2


char *variables[26];
int used_ids[26]={0};

char* concat(char* s1, char* s2, char* s3);
char* int_to_string(int i);
int count_digits(int n);
void action(int code, char id, char* value);

int yyerror();
int yylex();



%}

%union {
    int i;
    char c;
    struct expression{
            int code_action;
            char id;
            char* value;
    } expression;
}

%type <i> INT
%type <c> ID
%type <expression> expr

%token SUM SUB MUL DIV
%token IS
%token ID
%token INT
%token LPAR RPAR
%token EOLN


%left SUM
%left SUB
%left MUL
%left DIV

%%

expr_lst : 
      expr_lst expr EOLN    { action( $2.code_action, $2.id, $2.value ); }
    | expr EOLN             { action( $1.code_action, $1.id, $1.value ); }
    ;


expr :  ID IS expr      { $$.code_action=ASSIGN; $$.id = $1; $$.value = $3.value; }
      | INT             { $$.code_action=DEFAULT; $$.id=DEFAULT; $$.value = int_to_string($1); }
      | ID              { $$.code_action=SHOW; if(used_ids[$1-'a']!= 0){$$.id = $1; $$.value = variables[$1-'a'];}else{char string[2]; string[0]=$1;  string[1]=0;$$.id = $1; $$.value=string;}}
      | expr SUM expr   { $$.code_action=SHOW; $$.id=DEFAULT; strcpy($$.value, concat($1.value,"+",$3.value));}
      | expr SUB expr   { $$.code_action=SHOW; $$.id=DEFAULT; strcpy($$.value, concat($1.value,"-",$3.value));}
      | expr MUL expr   { $$.code_action=SHOW; $$.id=DEFAULT; strcpy($$.value, concat($1.value,"*",$3.value));}
      | expr DIV expr   { $$.code_action=SHOW; $$.id=DEFAULT; strcpy($$.value, concat($1.value,"/",$3.value));}
      | LPAR expr RPAR  { $$ = $2; }
      ;



%%


int yyerror( char* m ) {
   fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", m );
}

int main() {
  return yyparse();
}

void action(int code, char id, char* value){
    /*for(int i =0; i<26;i++){
        printf("%c---%s\n", 'a'+i,variables[i]);
    }*/
    switch(code){
        case SHOW:
            printf("%s\n", value);
            break;
        case ASSIGN:
            variables[(int)id-'a'] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(value));
            strcpy(variables[(int)id-'a'], value);
            used_ids[(int)id-'a'] = 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}

char* concat(char* s1, char* s2, char* s3 ){

    char* final_string = malloc(sizeof(s1)+sizeof(s2)+sizeof(s3));

    char* ss1=malloc(sizeof(s1));
    char* ss2=malloc(sizeof(s2));
    char* ss3=malloc(sizeof(s3));
    strcpy(ss1, s1);    
    strcpy(ss2, s2);    
    strcpy(ss3, s3);    
    strcpy(final_string, ss1);  
    strcat(final_string, " ");  
    strcat(final_string, ss2);  
    strcat(final_string, " ");  
    strcat(final_string, ss3);
    return final_string;
}

char* int_to_string(int i){
    char* final_string= malloc(count_digits(i)*sizeof(char));
    sprintf(final_string, "%d", i);
    return final_string;
}

int count_digits(int n){
    int count = 0;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        n /= 10;
        ++count;
    }
}
```

And it respective lex file:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include "interpret.tab.h"
%}

%x string
%x substring
%%

[\t ]+      /* ignore whitespace */ ;
"+"         { return SUM; }
"-"         { return SUB; }
"*"         { return MUL; }
"/"         { return DIV; }

":="        {return IS;}

"("         { return LPAR; }
")"         { return RPAR; }

[a-z]       { yylval.c = yytext[0];return ID; }

[0-9]+      { yylval.i = atoi( yytext ); return INT; }

[\n]        { return EOLN; }

.           { printf("Illegal character %c: ", *yytext); }
```

What I want is:

With input:

```
a:=4+5
b:=a+2
b
```

The output should be:

```
4+5+2
```

Now it's correct, but if I write the input (in the same execution)

```
a
```

The output is: 4+5+2.

Otherwise, if (in another execution) my input is:

```
a:=4+5
b:=2+a
b
```

First input in 2+4+5, and if I write a, the output is 4+5, without problems.

It seems that, when the first expressions of an operation is a letter, it puts the value in the correct place of array for the main variable (in case b:=a+4, the main would be b), and it overwrites the value of $1 if it's a letter.

Could you help me to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is full of buffer overruns, undefined behaviour and memory leaks, none of which have much to do with your use of bison/yacc. Under those circumstances, pretty well any output is possible.

Here are a few of the errors (the ones I noticed without a full examination):

```
char* concat(char* s1, char* s2, char* s3 ){
    char* final_string = malloc(sizeof(s1)+sizeof(s2)+sizeof(s3));
```

`sizeof(s1)` is the size of a pointer-to-char, which is probably either 4 or 8, depending on whether you're compiling in a 32- or 64-bit environment. It is computed at compile-time, so it has nothing to do with the run-time length of the string pointed to by `s1`. That would be `strlen(s1)`.

But it is not sufficient to change all the `sizeof`s to `strlen`s. You also need to allocate enough room for the space characters you are about to insert into the string, and for the NUL terminator at the end.

```
    char* ss1=malloc(sizeof(s1));
    char* ss2=malloc(sizeof(s2));
    char* ss3=malloc(sizeof(s3));
    strcpy(ss1, s1);    
    strcpy(ss2, s2);    
    strcpy(ss3, s3);
```

The allocations have the same problem as above: you use `sizeof` instead of `strlen` and you also don't add 1 for the NUL terminator. In addition, you never `free()` the storage for the temporary strings so they all end up leaking.

Rather than fixing all that, I suggest you just delete these six lines. There is no need to make temporary copies. `strcat` does not overwrite the string pointed to by its second argument, so you could just use `s1`, `s2` and `s3` in the `strcat` calls.

Even better would be to just use `snprintf`:

```
char* concat(const char* s1, const char* s2, const char* s3) {
    size_t len = strlen(s1) + srlen(s2) + strlen(s3) + 3;
    char* result = malloc(len);
    snprintf(result, len, "%s %s %s", s1, s2, s3);
    return result;
}
```

Note: If you are serious about learning how to program computers, you will not just copy that into your prject. You will try to understand exactly what it does. You should be able to clearly state the reason for the `+ 3` in the computation of `len`, the reason the parameters to `concat` are declared as `const char*` instead of `char*` and how `snprintf` safely produces the concatenation of the three strings.

You also need to look at the code which calls `concat`:

```
  strcpy($$.value, concat($1.value,"+",$3.value));
```

You do not inititalise `$$.value` to point to a string buffer, so you have no way to know that what it points to even exists, never mind being long enough to copy the result of `concat`. But you have no reason to copy that value anyway; you know that `concat` returns a freshly-allocated string. So you can just use it'

```
$$.value = concat($1.value, "+", $3.value);
```

Again, it is important for you to *understand* and not just copy. What is the difference between the assignment and the call to `strcpy`?

Once you fix all that, you still leak memory because you never `free()` the allocated strings. So you should think about when and how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much.
The truth is that I usually have many problems with C..
I suppose that the +3 in the malloc is to make spaces for the null terminators of each of the strings, as you explain here "The allocations have the same problem as above: you use size instead of strlen and you also do not add 1 for the NUL terminator. "

The difference between assignment and call to strcpy I understand that is that an assignment is assigning to a variable a memory address and a call to strcpy saves the data that there's in one memory address in anotherone... I'm not 100% sure .

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning pointers to local variables that become dangling when those local variables go out of scope.  For example in the code for IDs you have:

```
{char string[2]; string[0]=$1;  string[1]=0;$$.id = $1; $$.value=string;}
```

`string` here is a local on-stack array that goes away as so as this block is exited, so `$$.value` become dangling, and any use of it is undefined.

Then too, you're using `strcpy` to overwrite a string with a longer string, without checking the size, which is also undefined behavior.

Whenever you deal with pointers, you need to track the lifetimes of the things being pointed at and make sure you don't use the pointers after the lifetime has finished.  Whenever you use pointers to arrays (such as strings), you need to track the size of the underlying storage array and make sure you don't exceed it.